# Display Invoice via HTML rathen than PDF?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, invoice

I'm using Prawn to generate invoices as PDFs on the fly, which open in Adobe Acrobat.  Is there a quick way to have that same invoice display as HTML, or at least be viewable from within my web app while retaining the layout, rather than opening up a new window/PDF?  I've been unable to find any good example or suggestions. Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `send_data` in your controller action to open required files in the browser.

Check out the following [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292625/rails-prawn-pdf-show-up-in-browser-etc) for more info