# Prawn : Print existing PDF

Tags: ruby, prawn

I Have a model called Magazine with a number and a pdf file.

I try to access this url /magazine/:number.pdf

In my controller I do :

> @magazine = Magazine.find_by_number params[:number]

But How can I display the PDF ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  ...
  format.pdf do
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new # don't know exactly how your document is stored
    send_data pdf.render, filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
  end
end
```

Don't forget to register the MimeType too in an initializer:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming yours is an MVC application and you are using some web framework like Rails ,

```
 send_data pdf.render, :filename => "filename.pdf", :type => "application/pdf"
```

References

[Prawn shown up PDF generated in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293155/1067466)